# Does weakly Riemann integrable implies strongly Riemann integrable in operator theory?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $f:[0,1]\to X$ be a function where $X$ is a Banach algebra. We will say $f$ is strongly Riemann integrable if the limit of the sum $\sum_{i=1}^k f(t_i)(t_{i}-t_{i-1})$ as nets where the poset is the set of all partions $\{0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_k=1\}$ of $[0,1]$ with refinement as order. We say $f$ is weakly Riemann integrable means for all linear functionals $x^\ast$ on $X$ we have $x^\ast(f)$ is Riemann integrable. My question is are both definitions equivalent?

Comment: Since one says strongly and one says weakly, they are probably related in the following way: any strongly Riemann integrable function is weakly integrable, but the converse may not hold in general

Comment: @FShrike can you provide an example for the Converse.

Comment: I have never encountered these definitions or studied such related areas of operator theory, so, no... but I'd hope it's Google-able

Comment: In "J. Gordon: Riemann Integration in Banach Spaces"  DOI: 10.1216/rmjm/1181072923 have a look at "Example 35". It is an example of a function $f:[0,1] \to c_0$ which is not Riemann integrable, but which is weakly continuous.

Comment: @FShrike: the fact that strongly Riemann integrable implies weakly Riemann integrable is obvious from the definitions, and clearly obvious to OP. And OP is asking about the converse. Is there any point to your comment, besides being snarky?

Comment: @MartinArgerami No snark intended. It was a quick remark about a general principle, the OP should know that 9 times out of 10 the “weak” and “strong” definitions are inequivalent. I made no claim about any of the actual implications between the two concepts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No this is not true in general.
See this following example.[image]

This is from a paper by Russell Jordon,who have nicely written the theory of integration on banach spaces.
I am ataching the link for the papers, interested people must see this.
https://doi.org/10.1216/rmjm/1181072923

Comment: Very nice 